# Does unwanted extra jar files makes performance issue

Tags: java, performance, jar

I have one question regarding **unwanted extra jar files**.

First I had planned to do the project using Spring MVC 3.0 and Hibernate and created web project adding those library files. Later I decided not to use those technologies and use other technologies and added supported jar files as per new technologies and forget to remove the earlier jar files.

My question is, is there **PERFORMANCE** issue if there are unwanted jar files in our WEB-INF/lib folder? (consider that the un-wanted jar files that are there of larger size)

Thanks in advance.

**Note:** I have not searched for the same anywhere, so thought to ask here as response here would be short and more clear...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your container, there may be an impact on resident memory, as the ClassLoader may preload or cache the classes on the class-path.

If that's the case, and your memory is constrained by memory, then the additional strain on the garbage collector because of the reduced memory availability, could have a performance impact.

Generally speaking, that's not the case - but it is good practice to keep your project clean of it's dependencies to help with maintenance. Not least, the package size will be reduced!